# Use <a> to trigger a change in style

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller

I currently am trying to change the style of my page on the push of a button - the button is part of a dropdown. Everything I try does not seem to work, 
here is what I'm trying:

`<a href="#" onclick="@Url.Action("~Views/Customer/css/Hide.css")">Lead</a></li>`

Comment: Did you forgot to add `escape (\") or '` in `Action()`

Comment: 1.) Why not using `<button>` 2.) Change the className not the whole css data like `document.getElementById('pagecontainer').className = 'newpagecontainer';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with this line of code looks scary !

```
<a href="#" onclick="@Url.Action("~Views/Customer/css/Hide.css")">Lead</a></li>
```

If you want to change the style for a particular container ? or change the entire stylesheet ?

If later is the case, then you need to hold the current stylesheet value somewhere, may be in ViewBag or even Session. And then check when you are including in your layout, something on this lines..

```
@if(ViewBag.Style == "red")
{
  Styles.Render("~Views/Customer/css/Hide.css");
}
else if(ViewBag.Style == "blue")
{
  // you get the idea...
}
```

Comment: @C.Bishop pls mark this as answer if this helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Have two `<link />` tags defined like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="onclick.css" disabled id="onclick" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="offclick.css" disabled id="offclick" />
```

Using the jQuery, you can easily give the control to the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="style-change">Change Style</a>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("#style-change").click(function () {
        if ($("#onclick").prop("disabled")) {
            $("#onclick").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#offclick").prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("#onclick").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#offclick").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use JQuery you can do this within one line:

```
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' id='extracss' href='"~Views/Customer/css/Hide.css"' type='text/css' />");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help (y)